# Почему на андроиде выпадающее меню css работает, а на айфоне нет?

Tags: css3, html5

Почему на андроиде выпадающее меню на чистом css работает нормально, а на айфоне этот код не работает?

Как сделать чтобы он работал?

```css
.dropdown__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 38vw;
  background-color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #F8E31A;
  z-index: 3;
}

.dropdown__wrapper:hover > .dropdown__item {
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown__wrapper:focus > .dropdown__item {
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown__item {
  text-align: start;
  color: #F8E31A;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown__link {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F8E31A;
  padding: .3rem;
  letter-spacing: .6rem;
}

.dropdown__link:hover {
  color: black;
  background: #F8E31A;
}

.dropdown__link:focus {
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  background: #F8E31A;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown__wrapper"><a class="dropdown__link">наши достижения <span class="dropdown__arrow arrow"></span></a>
                <li class="dropdown__item"><a class="dropdown__link"  href="https://youtu.be/lbuHD-obfM4">чемпионат города 2023</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown__item"><a class="dropdown__link" href="https://youtu.be/nyOZhTUFDN0">чемпионат края 2023</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown__item"><a class="dropdown__link" href="https://youtu.be/c0OfV2ryEDM">чемпионат России 2023</a></li>                                        
                <li class="dropdown__item"><a class="dropdown__link" href="https://youtu.be/-laKT__5Q-c">чемпионат Европы 2023</a></li>    
                <li class="dropdown__item"><a class="dropdown__link" href="https://www.instagram.com/p/CmEAed9qu72/?igshid=MDJmNzVkMjY=">чемпионат Мира 2023</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Вероятно поэтому https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35187970

Comment: спасибо большое, это помогло!!!! вы спасли мой мозг от взрыва))